# Predicting what time will a John go to the gym tomorrow?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, predictive-modeling

I have a data set which contains the below columns:

```
Name    Day      Start_Gym_Time   End_Gym_Time
John    Monday   16:00            17:30
John    Tuesday  14:00            14:42
John    Tuesday  15:55            17:40
```

I need some advice on how to predict when will John go to the gym next? I am planning to use `scikit-learn` for trying out various algorithms? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: welcome :-)  can you narrow down what kind of advice you are looking for? otherwise this question is a bit broad

Comment: thank you for replying . I am looking to find examples of similar problems .. what algorithm would you choose to predict the time in the above scenario ..  ? Any help would be appreciated. How would you go about to solve such a problem . Thank you !!

Comment: @oW_ i hope that made it clear ?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by plotting some of the raw data. You might look at histograms of start times/stop times to see what the range of values are. You could also plot the start times as a time series to see if there are any long range patterns (i.e maybe as the week goes on John starts getting tired and showing up at the gym later).